# How to setup a condition in anylogic, that will return true, only when specific message is received?

Tags: anylogic, agent

Good day,
I'm trying in AnyLogic to make block "Ped Select Output" (from Pedestrian library) select output based on the received message, using the command in conditions table `receive("go");`. This block is located in Main, while the message is supposed to be sent from the agent tab (MyAgent) using the command `send("go", main.pedSource);`. Yet if I try to launch this model I get the error "Type mismatch, cannot convert void to boolean". I believe I have incorrectly selected one of the commands (or maybe both), thus I hope for advice about it. Thanks in advance for the answer.
P.s. check screenshots, for more detailed information.
P.p.s. the model, that is presented on screenshots is just an oversimplified example of the real model (that's why 4 out of 5 outputs of the block are connected to one place).
[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QdbR.png)
[agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcOaY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each condition in the selectoutput should return a boolean... a boolean can be true or false

Some example of booleans are 3==2, 5>4, agent.priority==1, etc

These things are booleand because they are true or false

you are putting in the condition a function that doesn't return anything (receive) and I have absolutely no idea what is in your head that would suggest that this might work in any way...

I suggest you add a variable in your ped agent that defines what the pedestrian should do...

Comment: Okey, first, I have an idea what boolean variable is. Second, the logic was something like this "if pedestrian previously received a message saying "go" the condition will interpret that as true, if he received some other message(or no message at all) it would return false. I also realize, that something in the command I wrote is wrong, since it doesn't receive anything, and maybe instead it should be something like ```receivedmsg="go";```, yet I don't know the exact command, and this is why I asked for advice.

Comment: then add a variable called message in your agent and when your agent gets a message use message=whateverMessageYouReceived

Then you can do message.equals("go or whatever") in your conditions